# Can we insert groups of AD to sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am facing hard time while knowing more about AD integration with sonarqube. I have a group in my Active directory called **Developers**. this **Developers** group has ten members. so what I am looking for is, As I authenticated Sonarqube with my AD how can I make replication of same group **Developers** in sonarqube. I though in a way that

when all the ten users of **Developers** group got login in sonarqube server then I will create a group with name Developers and then I will add all the 10 users to group **Developers**. is this is a right manner or any other official way to do it. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enable Group Mapping](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin#LDAPPlugin-GroupMapping) (by providing the group-related configuration values) and this group creation and membership will happen automatically.

You should be aware though that this group mapping is all-or-nothing. You cannot turn group mapping on and then try to manage membership in additional groups directly in SonarQube. Membership in such local groups will be wiped out by group synchronization the next time the user logs in.

Comment: Ann Thanks a lot for answering most of my question not only this. May I know what do you mean by all or nothing above.

Comment: it means you can't synchronize only some of the groups and ignore others.

Comment: Anna got it. So if I need to sync group which is in AD do I need create a same group in sonarqube groups  with same name which is in AD right? if I do this and a user get login will he get join in that group automatically?

Comment: But when I authenticated with LDAP I didn't seen any groups created.  this is my groups configuration `ldap.group.baseDn=CN=groups,DC=companyroot,DC=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))` is this is correct? @G. ANN. For user Mapping I used service accounts.

Comment: @Sam it's probably time to start a new thread on the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube)

Comment: @ G.Ann I posted it there can you please help me out